# Using an object in another object java

Tags: java, eclipse

So I'm setting a node class that shows links between one node and another to find the shortest route. I decided to use a seperate object class to store the links between node A and B to avoid using two-dimensional arrays.

After saving the project in eclipse, just as a checkpoint so I don't lose my data, all of a sudden red lines appeared under any calls of DistanceBetween, saying that the method doesn't exist in that object class, although it does, as you'll see.

Note: Any bolded part is throwing an error, in Node. Generally it states that the method doesn't exist in DistanceBetween, or that the constructor (int, int) is wrong, when it is not.

Should I use extend, a package?

```
public class DistanceBetween{

    private int thisAddress;
    private int distanceBetween;

    public DistanceBetween(int myAddress, int myDistance){
        thisAddress = myAddress;
        myDistance = distanceBetween;
    }

    public int getAddress(){
        return thisAddress;
    }

    public void setAddress(int newAddress){
        thisAddress = newAddress;
    }

    public int getDistance(){
        return distanceBetween;
    }

    public void setDistance(int newDistance){
        distanceBetween = newDistance;
    }

}










public class Node{

    private int address;
    private int distance;
    private Node[] connectedNodes;
    private DistanceBetween[] distances;
    private boolean intersection;

    public Node(int myAddress, Node[] myConnected, DistanceBetween[]
            myDistances, boolean isIntersection){
        address = myAddress;
        connectedNodes = myConnected;
        distances = myDistances;
        intersection = isIntersection;
    }

    public int getThisAddress(){
        return address;
    }

    public void setThisAddress(int newAddress){
        address = newAddress;
    }

    public Node[] getConnected(){
        return connectedNodes;
    }

    public void connectTwo(Node a, Node b){
        for(int x = 0; x < a.getConnected().length; x++){
            if(a.getConnected()[x].getThisAddress() == 0){

            }
        }
    }

    public DistanceBetween[] getDistances(){
        return distances;
    }

    public void setDistances(DistanceBetween[] newDistances){
        distances = newDistances;
    }

    public void addLink(Node a, Node b, int thisDistance){
        DistanceBetween[] holderDistanceA = a.getDistances();
        DistanceBetween[] holderDistanceB = a.getDistances();
        int flags = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < holderDistanceA.length; x++){
            if(holderDistanceA[x].**getAddress()** == 0){
                DistanceBetween aAndB = new **DistanceBetween(b.getThisAddress(),thisDistance);**
                holderDistanceA[x] = aAndB;
                flags++;
                break;
            }

        }

        for(int x = 0; x < holderDistanceB.length; x++){
            if(holderDistanceB[x].**getAddress()** == 0){
                DistanceBetween bAndA = new    **DistanceBetween(a.getThisAddress(),thisDistance);**
                holderDistanceB[x] = bAndA;
                break;
            }

        }

        if(flags < 1){
            System.out.println("Error, cannot add a link, link load is full.");
        }

        a.setDistances(holderDistanceA);
        b.setDistances(holderDistanceB);
    }

    public int getDistanceBetween(Node a, Node b){
        int result = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < a.getDistances().length; x++){
            if(a.getDistances()[x].**getAddress()** == b.getThisAddress()){
                result = a.getDistances()[x].**getDistance()**;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public boolean equals(Node a, Node b){
        if(a.address == b.address){
            return true;
        }else
            return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Compiles fine for me once I remove the `*`s from e.g. `**getAddress()**` - clean your eclipse project and see if the error goes away.

Comment: same here, everything compiles...

Comment: Those were supposed to be bold syntax for this site, I don't know why they kept them.

Comment: Ah, it was because I didn't hit save all, I just saved the node class. Apparently eclipse doesn't like one saved and one not saved. Sorry about that!

Comment: BTW, the "myDistance = distanceBetween;" in the constructor is probably a bug...

Comment: (I usually always write this.name = name; to avoid this kind of errors...)

Answer (score 0):

Your code compiles fine, it would appear that you have the 2 classes in different packages. To fix you can:

1. put the 2 classes into the same package
2. import the `DistanceBetween` package into the `Node` class.

   `import yourpackagename.DistanceBetween;`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not have a class named DistanceBetween somewhere else in your project, or, in case you do, that you're importing the right one where the DistanceBetween code you posted is intended to be used.

The Open Type tool in Eclipse (Ctrl + Shift + T) allows you to search for the location of classes along your workspace.